# C# Problema al conectarme a mi BD

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, visual-studio-2015

Buenas tengo mi proyecto de **Visual Studios**, hecho con `C#`, de la siguiente manera:

[image]

En **Controladores\Conductor.cs** quiero hacer uso de mi **Conexion\conexion.cs**

Esta es mi **conexion.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;


namespace pruebaTecnicaDGT
{
  public  class Conexion{
        private const string server = "localhost";
        private const string bd = "dgt";
        private const string user = "root";
        private const string password = "";

        private string ConnectionString;
        private SqlConnection con;



        public Conexion() {
            this.ConnectionString = "Data Source="+server+";Initial Catalog="+bd+";User Id="+user+";Password="+password;
            this.con = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString);
        }


        public void conectar() {
            this.con.Open();
        }

        public void desconectar() {
            this.con.Close();
        }


        public SqlConnection getConexion() {
            return this.con;
        }

        public void prueba() {
            Console.Write("HOla");
        }

    }
}
```

Este es mi fichero **Conductor.cs** donde usare mi **Conexion**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;



namespace pruebaTecnicaDGT
{
    class Conductor{
        Conexion con;

        public Conductor() {
            con = new Conexion();
            con.prueba();
        }

        public void listarTodos() {
            this.con.conectar();

            string query = "SELECT * FROM conductores;";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, this.con.getConexion());
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            try
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        String.Format("{0}, {1}",
                        reader["id"], 
                        reader["dni"],
                        reader["nombre"],
                        reader["apellidos"],
                        reader["puntos"])
                    );
                }
            }
            finally
            {

                reader.Close();
            }




            this.con.desconectar();
        }

    }
}
```

Como ven estoy haciendo una simple prueba en la que primero **se conecte a mi BD**  y , posteriormente, haga **una consulta a la bd** desde **Conductor.cs**.

El **primer problema** que tuve fue que cuando usaba la instanciaba la *Clase* **conexion.cs**  dentro de la *Clase* **Conductor.cs** no me la reconocia, hice una **chapucilla** que era ponerle todo el mismo `namespace` algo que, la verdad, si saben mejorarlo lo agradeceria.

Mi **segundo problema** ya si esta enfocado en la **conexion** debido a que solvente el problema del `namespace` con lo que cite anteriormente(*primer problema*). Y es que no me esta haciendo bien la **conexion** y ni muhco menos hace la **consulta**. Realmente no se donde esta el problema. Hace un tiempecito que no toco `C#`.

El **OUTPUT** del programa es el siguiente :

```
El subproceso 0x40f8 terminó con código 0 (0x0).
'pruebaTecnicaDGT.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: pruebaTecnicaDGT.vshost.exe): 'C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\pruebaTecnicaDGT\pruebaTecnicaDGT\bin\Debug\pruebaTecnicaDGT.exe' cargado. Símbolos cargados.
'pruebaTecnicaDGT.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: pruebaTecnicaDGT.vshost.exe): 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
Ir a: paso a paso por procedimientos en código 'pruebaTecnicaDGT.App..ctor' que no es de usuario
Ir a: paso a paso por procedimientos en código 'pruebaTecnicaDGT.App.InitializeComponent' que no es de usuario
'pruebaTecnicaDGT.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: pruebaTecnicaDGT.vshost.exe): 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework.Aero2\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'pruebaTecnicaDGT.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: pruebaTecnicaDGT.vshost.exe): 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_es_b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.resources.dll' cargado. El módulo se compiló sin símbolos.
HOla'pruebaTecnicaDGT.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: pruebaTecnicaDGT.vshost.exe): 'C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Temp\VisualStudio.XamlDiagnostics.3288\WpfXamlDiagnosticsTap.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'pruebaTecnicaDGT.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: pruebaTecnicaDGT.vshost.exe): 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop\7.1.40304.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.dll' cargado. El módulo se compiló sin símbolos.
'pruebaTecnicaDGT.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: pruebaTecnicaDGT.vshost.exe): 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\UIAutomationTypes\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\UIAutomationTypes.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
El subproceso 0x1edc terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso 0x42bc terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El subproceso 0x28f8 terminó con código 0 (0x0).
El programa '[3288] pruebaTecnicaDGT.vshost.exe' terminó con código 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: En el codigo defines un `try` pero donde esta el `catch` ? sino captura el mensaje de error como te enteras porque razon esta fallando

Comment: Lo he probado con el `catch(Exception e){ Console.Write("error  => "+e);}`  pero no arroja ningun error, de hecho no entra por el `catch`

Comment: Imagino que el error estará dando en `command.ExecuteReader()` o en la función `Conectar`, y como no estan dentro del `try`no puedes capturar la excepción.

Comment: Como depuración, mete todo lo de la función listarTodos() dentro de un bloque try - catch para ver en dónde se encuentra el error.

Comment: Tu output que pusiste no es la excepcion, de hecho parece no la estas controlando. En mis proyectos he tenido esos output pero no son causantes de errores.